# Cannot send GraphQL query from Apollo Client to Rails GraphQL backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-ruby

I'm using Rails as GraphQL backend using plugin [graphql-ruby](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby). On front end size, I'm using Apollo Client for my react/redux project.

Here is my front end side:

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4001/graphql',
});
export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({ networkInterface });
```

On my backend, I have tested successfully following query on `http://localhost:4001/graphiql`.

```
query{
  allAuthors{
    full_name,
    books{
      book_name,
      book_description,
      isbn
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my rails route config:

```
if Rails.env.development?
    mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql"
  end

  post "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute"
```

I try to get similar data from front end side. Here is my code:

```
    const ALL_AUTHORS_QUERY = gql`
      query allAuthors {
        full_name,
        books{
          book_name,
          book_description,
          isbn
        }
      }
    `;
    apolloClient
      .query({
        query: ALL_AUTHORS_QUERY,
      })
      .then(response => console.log(response.data));
  }
```

But after that, I meet following exception:

```
POST http://localhost:4001/graphql 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

Please tell me what have I wrong ? Thanks

**@Edit 1:** 
I also try different query on client but the problem still same.

```
   const ALL_AUTHORS_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    allAuthors {
      full_name
      books {
        book_name
        book_description
        isbn
      }
    }
  }
`;
apolloClient
  .query({
    query: ALL_AUTHORS_QUERY,
  })
  .then(response => console.log(response.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, you have named your query `allAuthors` when `allAuthors` is a GraphQL type. You don't have to name your query that's optional. However, `allAuthors` is a required type of the query root.

`query allAuthors {` your query starts with this,  when it should be like this `query { allAuthors`

Comment: Can you explain for me in detail please. I don't get it.

Comment: I have updated as you said. the problem still the same. I have updated my question for your query. Please take a look.